# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in vs13

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I am using C# Visual Studio 2013 for Windows, and when I try to debug, this error happens: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage));
    }
}
```

The problem is on the navigation line. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to navigate in the constructor (bad idea) its quite possible that Frame isn't ready to navigate yet. Could you navigate in something else, like the Window_Loaded event?

Comment: i tried to send it to a function first and try to avigate fron that function but its the same error... this is what its says:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in sample.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely happens because `Frame` is still `null` at the point when you call `Navigate` I would recommend moving this code else where or adding a nullity check.

Answer (score 4):

Constructors are for two things, actually constructing the object (allocating memory and so forth, done for you by the framework) and initializing data, event handlers, and the like. NOTHING else should be done in it, certainly nothing like page navigation.

The Frame object is likely not created at this point, and you shouldn't be using it anyways. Instead, set up an event:

Either:

```
<Page ...
     Loaded="Page_Loaded"/>
```

or:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += Page_Loaded;
}
```

Then have a function like so:

```
private void Page_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage));
}
```

Besides being much better practice, this will likely solve your exception.

Comment: Surely once `this.InitializeComponent();` has finished running, all the initialisation will be finished? If not, then that doesn't seem particularly intuitive, unless its perhaps async or something is it?

Comment: @dantechguy There's a reason we have the loaded event. Just because the window is done initializing doesn't mean all the child controls are